# Manga where the female lead and her cousin are summoned to another world. The female lead has light magic and is a goddess' daughter

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga, isekai

In this manga, the female lead (FL) and her cousin are summoned to another world. One of them is the goddess' daughter with light magic and the other is summoned with her by mistake. They are summoned on the day of the FL's grandmother's funeral.

The FL wears glasses which makes her look ugly while, without glasses, she is pretty beautiful. Her cousin shows signs of light magic and throws a tantrum to kick the FL out. The commander pities the FL and asks her to stay in the knight's quarter for a few days.

The FL cooks and does chores for the knight division and is the actual goddess' daughter. She heals the commander after he comes from a battle where the FL's cousin couldn't use light magic . She falls for the commander and sleeps with him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, what colour was the female lead's hair, and what colour was her cousin's hair?

Comment: The manga was in black and white. The female leads hair is black and wears round ugly glasses and i don't know her cousin hair colour . It probably a lighter shade.

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *[The Knight Commander Wants to Monopolize the Former Glasses Girl](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/kishi-danchou-wa-moto-megane-shoujo-wo-hitorijime-shitai)*.

> I was caught up in **a trip to another world and was treated as a nuisance**, but the person who helped me was the commander of the Second Knights, Leon, who was super strong and handsome! He was blunt but kind and always took care of me. But why does he get so nervous **when I take off my glasses**?

While at the grandmother's funeral, Rina and her cousin Mayu were summoned to another world. Mayu insists that she's the one chosen by the goddess, proves it with some simple test, and everyone ignores Rina. She's taken in by the knights, and the commander eventually sees her without her glasses on and notices that she's beautiful. She keeps the thick glasses on to avoid attention, particularly from the incredibly jealous Mayu.

[image: Thick glasses, summoning ceremony, MC without glasses on.]